# How to implement trigger after insertion?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, triggers

I have a column named `htmlContent` which `stores HTML Content` in table `EEmailData` and a column named `EEmailDataID` which is `unique ID` of this table or I can say `primary key of this table.`

Now what I want to do is I want to `create a trigger` which would get this primary key from this table and insert this `EEmailDataID` in column `htmlContent` on a specific location.

I think this would take place by `SUBSTRING` function. Can anybody suggest me some other solution?

Comment: `insert this EEmailDataID in column htmlContent on a specific location`. can you please explain this? do yo want to append the id to htmlContent  column?

Comment: suppose this htmlcontent column contains data like this **<a href="http://localhost:19763/BitBucket/GUEST/GuestForward.aspx?jzx=[GuestInviteFwd]" target="_blank" style="text-decoration: none;"><span style="font-size: 20px; font-family: Segoe UI, Arial; font-weight: none; color: #ffffff; white-space: nowrap; display: block;"><b>Invite Friends</b></span></a>** Now i want to add EEmailDataID after [GuestInviteFwd].

Comment: GuestInviteFwd where is this in the htmlcontent? or after `Invite Friends`??

Comment: GuestIviteFwd is in href of anchor tag.

Comment: its little hard. Is that `GuestIviteFwd`  is always like that? or is that `dynamic`? I mean its always `want to add EEmailDataID after `GuestInviteFwd`.?

Comment: no its not dynamic, its static.

Comment: did you checked  my answer? tried?

Comment: Yes, I tried your answer but after some modification and that worked for me..your answer somehow helped me..Thanks for this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this you need to add an `id`where you want to replace the `Primary key value`

Eg: `<a href="localhost:19763/BitBucket/GUEST/... ?GuestInviteFwd=uArAiAd`

And use the following trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER EEmailData_Trigg ON EEmailData
AFTER INSERT
AS
IF EXISTS (SELECT top(1)*
           FROM EEmailData p 
           JOIN inserted AS i 
           ON p.EEmailDataID = i.EEmailDataID 
          )
BEGIN
DECLARE @html VARCHAR(MAX),@id INT
SELECT @html=htmlContent ,@id=EEmailData 
FROM EEmailData 
WHERE EEmailDataID =(SELECT TOP(1) EEmailDataID FROM inserted)

UPDATE EEmailData
SET htmlContent=REPLACE(@html,'uArAiAd',@id)
WHERE EEmailDataID=@id

END
```

Now after trigger `uArAiAd` is replaced by EEmailDataID

also you can achieve this without trigger.
Just do the following after insert.

```
DECLARE @html VARCHAR(MAX),@id INT
--insert statements
SET @id=SCOPE_IDENTITY()
SELECT @html=htmlContent ,@id=EEmailData 
    FROM EEmailData 
    WHERE EEmailDataID =@id

    UPDATE EEmailData
    SET htmlContent=REPLACE(@html,'uArAiAd',@id)
    WHERE EEmailDataID=@id
```